# Angular7 async pipe crashes application

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, es6-promise, angular-promise

```
<!-- .html -->
<div class="modal-body">
  {{ doMath() | async }}
</div>
```

---

```
// .ts
async doMath() {
  const res = {};
  return await this.orderCollection.get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        const data = doc.data();
        data.owners.reduce((acum, cur) => {
          acum[cur] = (acum[cur] || 0) + data.price;
          return acum;
        }, res);
      });
      return res;
    });
}
```

I'm trying to display the result of this function using **Async Pipe**, but my browser crashes and the memory goes crazy.

BTW the code works fine if I run this async function in the `.ts` file and set the return result to a variable.

What I'm missing here?

P.S. If I replace this code with simple `Promise` it also crashes.

Comment: What are you actually expecting from that function? It seems practically obfuscated.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I expect an object, as I mentioned above the function works as expected when calling it inside the .ts file with .then and assign the return value to some variable.

Comment: The Async pipe is supposed to be working with observables and promises. Either make an observale and use that observale as your data source in your html file and fill the observale value using the current function or change this function and omit the await part and return the promise from this function and on successful retrieve of data just resolve the promise.

Comment: the problem is this one `return await this.orderCollection.get()` you should not call the `await` keyword since you're using `async pipe` in your view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using async pipe there is no need to use  :

```
return await this.orderCollection.get()
```

What you need to do is filter the data you want and use `| async` afterwords .

Read more about async pipes in angular here :https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe